# MSCRM 4.0 - Error Logging from a Custom Plugin

Tags: dynamics-crm

I am using mscrm 4.0 and .net 3.5.

I have written a custom plugin, that is erroring! (solving the error is not my question though)

When my dynamic entity code, tries to update the organisation, it errors with a generic Soap Exception "Server was not able to process request".

I need to look at the inner detail of the soap exception to figure out the problem.

So my question is - what is the best way to log errors and get all of the information from a soap exception - from custom plugin?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a try-catch then you could always catch a SoapException first then log the inner exception/detail property.

Comment: Hi thanks for replying. Im not sure i was clear enough, i wasnt sure what to do with the caught exception. I got this off msdn in the end.                                                        catch (SoapException soapException) { EventLog.WriteEntry("MSCRMWebService", "My Plugin Error: " + soapException.ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Error); throw; }.                              The thing i didnt know about was the "MSCRMWebService" event source that you had to add.

Comment: I had created my own event source, put it in the registry as normal. But still the events were not showing. So when i added "MSCRMWebService" as the event source, they started appearing.